# Azure Ad Graph API, Get User information and User Device Infromation

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I Am wondering if i can use the Azure Active Directory Graph Api to retrieve information about the user and the specific users devices and device information?

I managed to get som information by doing :

https://graph.windows.net/f2f535e0-294f-4704-befc-8ce754f10bd7/users/9da7eaba-78bf-4b54-844a-7918d40a6005?api-version=1.6

in Fiddler, and also pasting in a Authorization Bearer token in the header.
i get some general information but not anything about the devices assigned to the user or the devices id.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a user's owned devices through:

```
https://graph.windows.net/f2f535e0-294f-4704-befc-8ce754f10bd7/users/9da7eaba-78bf-4b54-844a-7918d40a6005/ownedDevices?api-version=1.6
```

The `ownedDevices` navigation property on the User returns you the devices owned by the user.

You can find information on all properties and navigation properties here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity.

Comment: As always you come to the rescue @juunas. It worked, thank you so much! :)